# Bind JavaScript jQuery click event on label AND on checkbox simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, label

I'm using labels for my form, like this :

```
<label for="foo" id="bar">Label</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="foo" />
```

I want to hide an element when the user uncheck the box, and show it otherwise.

The problem is, if I bind the click event to "foo", it'll only works when the user clicks on the checkbox itself and not on the label. Therefore, do I also need to bind a click event on the label ? Or should I enclose both elements within a span ?
My HTML already contains 2344 elements, so I'd like to do it without adding anything, and without doubling the JavaScript code or the selector, if possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of binding with the `click()` event, you should bind using the `change()` event, then however this change is triggered the outcome will be the same:

```
$('#foo').change(
    function(){
        // do whatever
    });
```

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer !

Answer (score 3):

The [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change) event should fire for the `input` whether the `label` or `input` is clicked:

```
$("#foo").change(function () { ... });
```

**Example** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/6LMXW/