# Style checkboxes as Toggle Buttons

Tags: html, css, checkbox, toggle

On my website, users can post articles and tag them accordingly using some pre-set tags. These tags are in the form of checkboxes. Example below:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="wpuf_post_tags[]" class="new-post-tags" value="Aliens" /> Aliens
<input type="checkbox" name="wpuf_post_tags[]" class="new-post-tags" value="Ghosts" /> Ghosts
<input type="checkbox" name="wpuf_post_tags[]" class="new-post-tags" value="Monsters" /> Monsters
```

As you might know, the checkboxes will look something like this:

> [ ] Aliens
>
> [o] Ghosts
>
> [ ] Monsters

I would like to do is have the checkbox being one large button with the value inside of it. And then make it have a "toggle" effect.

> [ Aliens ] **[ Ghosts ]** [ Monsters ]

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you have an example online that inspires you?

Comment: When you say "toggle effect", is that on hover?, on click? does it move the checbox?

Comment: @blackhawk
I don't have an example online that inspired me.

With the toggle effect I mean that on clicking the button the checkbox will be "marked" and stay that way until the form is submitted.

Afterwards all the "marked" checkboxes will be used as tags for the article.

Comment: @blachawk I think it should look like for example text formatting buttons in MS Word (italic, bold etc).

Comment: my little example - http://jsfiddle.net/r37boLbr/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check [this](http://jsbin.com/edipux/3/edit) out

**HTML**

```
<input id="chk_aliens" type="checkbox" name="wpuf_post_tags[]" class="vis-hidden new-post-tags" value="Aliens" />
<label for="chk_aliens">Aliens</label>

<input id="chk_ghosts" type="checkbox" name="wpuf_post_tags[]" class="vis-hidden new-post-tags" value="Ghosts" />
<label for="chk_ghosts">Ghosts</label>

<input id="chk_monsters" type="checkbox" name="wpuf_post_tags[]" class="vis-hidden new-post-tags" value="Monsters" />
<label for="chk_monsters">Monsters</label>
```

**CSS**

```
.vis-hidden {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}

label {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

input:focus + label {
  border-color: blue;
}

input:checked + label {
  border-color: red;
}

input:focus:checked + label {
  border-color: green;
}
```

Note that the last selector may not work in older IE.

Comment: I have a similar example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/r7vXE/), based on [this CSS Ninja article](http://www.thecssninja.com/css/custom-inputs-using-css). As per that article, IE8 and below don't support the `:checked` pseudo-class, so this falls apart in those browsers. As such, you need to ensure you are only serving these styles to capable browsers - one method is to use the `not()` pseudo-class - or put them all within a media query.

Comment: @CherryFlavourPez I just took a view at your example and I really like it. What I'm wondering however is if I would be better off using CSS to do the toggle-effect or use javascript/jquery instead.

Which would you recommend?

Comment: You could also use a [conditional IE body class](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/add-body-class-just-for-ie/) and apply these styles for browsers newer than IE8. So in IE8- you would see the normal checkboxes and for newer browser you'd have fancy styled labels.

Comment: As @Simon states, I'd say this is the perfect example of where [progressive enhancement](http://alistapart.com/article/understandingprogressiveenhancement) makes total sense. Just use the CSS version for capable browsers, and the fallback is a series of (perfectly usable) checkboxes. JavaScript just adds another layer of complexity (and you'd need to do two versions in that case, allowing for those users that have it disabled).

Answer (score 7):

This can be done using checkboxes and labels, the adjacent sibling selector – and the CSS3 `:selected` pseudo class.

HTML:

```
<span><input type="checkbox" id="c1"><label for="c1">[ Aliens ]</label></span>
<span><input type="checkbox" id="c2"><label for="c2">[ Ghosts ]</label></span>
<span><input type="checkbox" id="c3"><label for="c3">[ Monsters ]</label></span>
```

CSS:

```
input { display:none; }
input:checked ~ label { color:red; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/drTg2/

But be aware that this will easily fail in older browsers – because they don’t know `~` or `:checked`. And older IE have problems with checkboxes set to `display:none` – won’t transfer them when the form is submitted (although that can be overcome by other means of hiding, f.e. absolute positioning of the screen).

If you don’t insist on a pure HTML/CSS solution – there are many scripts / {js-framework-of-your-choice}-plugins out there, that help achieve the same effect.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do! How "dangerous" would it be to use this on my website? (hiding the checkboxes and using the labels to check/uncheck them?)

Comment: That depends on how important it is that it works in every browser – or if you can live with it not working in browsers that are a little older …

Comment: Note that you cannot tab through the checkboxes if you set display: none, also their value won't be submitted in a form. You should use a visibility-hidden class.

Comment: Actually, Simon’s answer using the selector `input:checked + label` is preferable – mine using ~ depends on the input and label being encapsulated in a further element (span).

Answer (score 3):

`Checkboxes`, `radio` buttons and `SELECT` elements have very limited styling capabilities and they vary widely across browsers.

You're better off accomplishing these using styled links or buttons, then using JavaScript to set the actual on/off appearance and form values.

Comment: That's exactly what I'd say, styling form elements is a pain in the neck, especially if it should be cross-browser.

Comment: The toggled buttons need to be submitted through a form though. I'm not sure how that would be possible using styled links or buttons.

Comment: Not only that, but they each have well-accepted use cases. Making checkboxes function like radio buttons breaks user experience standards.

Comment: Yes, it is much, much easier (if possible, at all) to make another element more "checkbox-like" than to make a checkbox more like any other element (speaking in styling).

Comment: Swen: you need to make CSS buttons, swap classes for on/off states and use hidden form fields to store the data by hooking up a JS click event to set the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can borrow ideas from this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196386/bind-javascript-jquery-click-event-on-label-and-on-checkbox-simultaneously)!   Try to bind your text and checkbox.  And then then try to use jquery to "toggle" the label associated to the checkbox.

You can then use styles and images to make the labels look like containers for checkboxes.  That is what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to have pictures with javascript `onclick` event that would change `img source` attribute. Then, put hidden control with given `id` and in the same `onclick` event use `document.getElementById('hiddencontrol').value = 1 - document.getElementById('hiddencontrol').value` (with 0 or 1 as default).

However, I don't know how to make it without Javascript.