# Force element state of input button to active with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have seen numerous stack posts and other online articles that say to force a button state to active, just add the "active" class to it. *This simply doesn't work*.

I have an input element of type button:

```
<input type="button" id="btn25" value="$25" class="checkout-btn" onclick="donateButton(25)">
```

In Chrome Dev Tools when I select the button, expand the `Force element state` panel, and check `:active`, that does exactly what I need (displays the button as if it's being actively clicked by the mouse).

[image]

But adding a class named "active" or "ACTIVE" or "activated" (as suggested by numerous answered posts) does nothing. I've tried this both with jquery, and by just adding it to the static html. And I don't see how it *could* do anything, since I don't have a class in my css named "active".

There must be a way in jquery to force element state to `:active` that does the same thing as when I check the `:active` box in dev tools.

Comment: Some libraries like [Bootstrap] use an `.active` class for applying their styles, which is perhaps where the confusion is coming from.  Why exactly is it that you are attempting to force an active or active-like state?  Understanding that might better inform how to answer this question.

Comment: Alexander, I have several donation buttons side-by-side with amounts on them, and when one of those buttons is clicked, I want it to remain appearing "clicked" (depressed), as a visual cue to the user which amount was selected.

Comment: @HerrimanCoder: It sounds like that may be better solved by tracking in your code which ones have been clicked and updating their classes/styling accordingly, rather than trying to awkwardly force this pseudo-class.

Comment: You could (should) use a checkbox instead of a button - style the checkbox so it looks like a button and "active" when "checked" (but without seeing a checkbox).

Comment: Does this answer your question (as an alternative to the actual question) : [Style checkboxes as toggle buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436450/style-checkboxes-as-toggle-buttons)

Comment: *I don't see how it could do anything, since I don't have a class in my css named "active"* - the key here is to **add a class named "active"**

Comment: David, you said the magic word: `pseudoclass` - I didn't know that's what it was called, and I think this probably answers my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740967/how-do-you-add-pseudo-classes-to-elements-using-jquery

Comment: That answer essentially says "add an 'active' class" :D

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me learn.