# jQuery - How to bind click event on label using jquery and get mouse click co-ordinates?

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I have following code to handle mouse click on label

```
//below function will be called when we click on label.
function showListClick(e, which, optWidth, item)
{
    mouseMoveHandler = function(e){
        if(e.pageX > 0 && e.pageY > 0)
            showItemList(e, which, optWidth, e.pageX, e.pageY);
    };
    jQuery("#"+item).click(mouseMoveHandler);
}
```

where `jQuery("#"+item)` is a label. I am binding one handler called `mouseMoveHandler` on click event and then from that function `showItemList()`, I am showing one popup menu. Here the problem is that in `mouseMoveHandler` handler I have put a condition that only show popup menu when `e.pageX and e.pageY > 0` because when I first click on label it returns Negative value.

Can anybody advice on this?

Comment: binding the event is like jQuery("#"+item).bind('click', mouseMoveHandler); not like jQuery("#"+item).click(mouseMoveHandler);
Is it possible to show your code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Actually I have series of functions and some dependent code so it will not be possible to show all codes in jsfiddle. But I am going to check your solution.

Comment: I tried your solution but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NullVoid, Hey, i have tried this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#foo").change(function () {
        var flag=true;
        $(document).mousemove(function(e){
            if(flag==true){
              $('#showOrHideMe').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
                flag=false;
            }
           }); 
    });
});
```

> [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6LMXW/53/)

It may help you getting your need.

refer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196386/bind-javascript-jquery-click-event-on-label-and-on-checkbox-simultaneously) and for mouse click [Here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position)

Comment: Hay! I'm appreciating it and checking the same and let you know afterwards :)